# does fluent handle the configuration also or I still need configuration.cfg.xml

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using fluent for mappings in my web application that uses nhibernate (just setting it up!).

Do I use fluent for the database configuration file or I use fluent for that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Fluent NHibernate for configuration as well, using what they call Fluent Configuration. You can find the documentation for Fluent Configuration [here](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/show/FluentConfiguration).

Here is an example of what it can look like when using Fluent NHibernate for the NHibernate configuration:

```
var sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()  
  .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.InMemory)  
  .Mappings(m =>  
    m.FluentMappings  
      .AddFromAssemblyOf<YourEntity>())  
  .BuildSessionFactory();
```